# how to use .live with autocomplete in jquery?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, live

I want to use autocomplete with .live function, but it gives syntax error

```
$("input[name=point]").live(function() {
    $(this).autocomplete({
        minLength:0,   //for local data
        delay:0,      //for local data
        source:function(request,response){
            //var param= {"action":"getSalePoints"};
            $.getJSON("controllers/Order.controller.php?action=getSalePoints",request,function(result){
                //create array for response objects
                var suggestions = [];
                //process response
                $.each(result, function(i, val){                                
                    //alert(val.number);
                    suggestions.push(val.number);
                });

                //pass array to callback
                response(suggestions);
            });


        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            var param={
                "action":"getSalePointNo",
                "point":ui.item.value
                };
            $.getJSON("controllers/Order.controller.php",param,function(result){            
                if(result == "0"){
                    $('#resultMsg').attr('class','errorMsg');
                }
                else{
                    alert(result);
                    $('[name=pointNo]', $(this).parents(".bill")).val(no);
                }

            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As 'mu is to short' suggested, you are not supplying the event type to the live function, you can try using 'focus' as the event type, try:

```
$("input[name=point]").live("focus", function() {
$(this).autocomplete({
    minLength:0,   //for local data
    delay:0,      //for local data
    source:function(request,response){
        //var param= {"action":"getSalePoints"};
        $.getJSON("controllers/Order.controller.php?action=getSalePoints",request,function(result){
            //create array for response objects
            var suggestions = [];
            //process response
            $.each(result, function(i, val){                                
                //alert(val.number);
                suggestions.push(val.number);
            });

            //pass array to callback
            response(suggestions);
        });


    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        var param={
            "action":"getSalePointNo",
            "point":ui.item.value
            };
        $.getJSON("controllers/Order.controller.php",param,function(result){            
            if(result == "0"){
                $('#resultMsg').attr('class','errorMsg');
            }
            else{
                alert(result);
                $('[name=pointNo]', $(this).parents(".bill")).val(no);
            }

        });
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

The `live` function takes [two arguments](http://api.jquery.com/live):

> **`.live( eventType, handler )`**
>   **Description:** Attach a handler to the event for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.

You're not supplying the `eventType` so you'll be triggering an error inside jQuery as it tries to work with a function as a string and an `undefined` value as a function.

Comment: I tried both signature, but .live( 'keyDown', handler ) did not work too

Comment: @sasola: `keyDown` isn't what you want, that would bind your autocompleter on every key-down and you want you autocompleter bound *before* any keys are pressed.